# Get property from text file or as class

Tags: c#, linq

I want to read a text file and store the data as a class or property. Text file will be something along the lines of this:

```
BoardSize: 4, 4
TurtlePos: 1, 1
TurtleDir: North
```

In Java I could do something similar with this:

```
List<Integer> boardSizes = stringArrayToIntList(configFile.getProperty(BOARD_SIZE).split(","));
```

But I can't figure it out in C# at all.

Something either with linq would be handy either.

Comment: Are you looking for a formal configuration approach or are you looking to read from a text file; is it .NetCore?

Comment: I am looking to read from a text file. It is.

Answer (score 0):

With no error handling

```
var lines = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("path");

string[] Split(string line) => line.Split(new[] { ':', ',', ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

var line0 = Split(lines[0]);
var line1 = Split(lines[1]);
var line2 = Split(lines[2]);


// Using anonymous types - in real life you probably want concrete classes. 
var board = new { N = Int32.Parse(line0[1]), M = Int32.Parse(line0[2])};
var turtle = new { X = Int32.Parse(line1[1]), Y = Int32.Parse(line1[2]), Dir = line2[1] };
```

For the test I used:

```
 var text = @"BoardSize: 4, 5
              TurtlePos: 2, 3
              TurtleDir: North";
var lines = text.Split(new[] { "\r\n" }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```